# Snowflake + copy a small sample of a table into a new one

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a table (A) with 1.000.000 records and I want to copy a small percentage (10%) of that table into another one (COPY_A) to try some things. What's the best approach to do it in Snowflake?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using [CTAS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-as-select-also-referred-to-as-ctas) and [SAMPLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample):

```
CREATE TABLE COPY_A 
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A SAMPLE (10);
```